# My jQuery script only runs once when I select a value

Tags: jquery, html

I 've been working on this jQuery script for many hours and I cannot find the bug, I would really appreciate help. All the comments and suggestions are welcome :)

When the user selects the number of volunteers to be inserted, my jQuery script should display the correct number of volunteers but for some reason it only displays three. 
Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

$(function(){

var number= $('#integrantes :selected').val();

if(number==3){
  $("#loscuatro").hide();
  $("#loscinco").hide();   
  $("#losseis").hide();   
  $("#lossiete").hide();   
  $("#losocho").hide();   
  $("#losnueve").hide();         
  $("#losdiez").hide();   

}else if(number==4){
  $("#loscinco").hide();   
  $("#losseis").hide();   
  $("#lossiete").hide();   
  $("#losocho").hide();   
  $("#losnueve").hide();   
  $("#losdiez").hide();   

}else if(number==5){
  $("#losseis").hide();   
  $("#lossiete").hide();   
  $("#losocho").hide();   
  $("#losnueve").hide();   
  $("#losdiez").hide();   

}else if(number==6){   
  $("#lossiete").hide();  
  $("#losocho").hide();   
  $("#losnueve").hide();   
  $("#losdiez").hide();       

} else if(number==7){
  $("#losocho").hide();   
  $("#losnueve").hide();   
  $("#losdiez").hide();
}else if(number==8){
  $("#losnueve").hide();   
  $("#losdiez").hide();    

}else if(number==9){
  $("#losdiez").hide();
}
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" class="ltr">    

           Number of team members 
                    <select name="integrantes" id="integrantes" >                
                <option  name="members"  value="3"   id="muestras" >3</option>
            <option  name="member4"  value="4"   id="muestra4">4</option>
        <option  name="member5"  value="5"   id="muestra5">5</option>
        <option  name="member6"  value="6"   id="muestra6">6</option>
        <option  name="member7"  value="7"   id="muestra7">7</option>
        <option  name="member8"  value="8"   id="muestra8">8</option>
        <option  name="member9"  value="9"   id="muestra9">9</option>           
        <option  name="member10"  value="10"   id="muestra10">10</option>

            </select>

 <h3>Volunteer 1</h3>
Name* <input id="Field0" />

 <h3>Volunteer 2</h3>
    Name* <input  />

 <h3>Volunteer 3</h3>
    Name* <input  />

<div id="loscuatro">  
<h3>Volunteer 4</h3>
    Name* <input  />

  <div id="loscinco">
<h3>Volunteer 5</h3>
    Name* <input  />

  <div id="losseis">
<h3>Volunteer 6</h3>
    Name* <input  />        

  <div id="lossiete">
<h3>Volunteer 7</h3>
    Name* <input  />  

  <div id="losocho">
<h3>Volunteer 8</h3>
    Name* <input  />                

  <div id="losnueve">
<h3>Volunteer 9</h3>
    Name* <input  />          

  <div id="losdiez">
<h3>Volunteer 10</h3>
    Name* <input  />  

   </div><!--fin de los diez-->                 
   </div><!--fin de los nueve-->                 
   </div><!--fin de los ocho-->                 
   </div><!--fin de los siete-->                 
   </div><!--fin de los seis-->         
   </div><!--fin de los cinco--> 
 </div><!--end of volunteer loscuatros-->   

</body>
</html>
```

I think this is not working because when the page loads, it automatically loads the first value (value 3). Am I missing a loop or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Following are the mistakes in your code:**

1) Your code is hanging,  ***wrap*** it using `.on('change', function(){})` eventhandler.

2) `.val()` returns the datatype as ***string*** so you need to use `.parseInt()`

```
var number= parseInt($('#integrantes :selected').val());
```

3)Then your full code should have **===** strict comparsion operator.

4)Once you hideout other, using `.show()` the needed `id`.

```
$(function () {
    $('#integrantes').on('change', function () {
        var number = parseInt($('#integrantes :selected').val());
        console.log(number);
        if (number === 3) {
            $("#loscuatro").hide();
            $("#loscinco").hide();
            $("#losseis").hide();
            $("#lossiete").hide();
            $("#losocho").hide();
            $("#losnueve").hide();
            $("#losdiez").hide();

        } else if (number === 4) {
            $("#loscuatro").show();
            $("#loscinco").hide();
            $("#losseis").hide();
            $("#lossiete").hide();
            $("#losocho").hide();
            $("#losnueve").hide();
            $("#losdiez").hide();

        } else if (number === 5) {
            $("#loscuatro").show();
            $("#loscinco").show();
            $("#losseis").hide();
            $("#lossiete").hide();
            $("#losocho").hide();
            $("#losnueve").hide();
            $("#losdiez").hide();

        } else if (number === 6) {
            $("#loscuatro").show();
            $("#loscinco").show();
            $("#losseis").show();
            $("#lossiete").hide();
            $("#losocho").hide();
            $("#losnueve").hide();
            $("#losdiez").hide();

        } else if (number === 7) {
            $("#loscuatro").show();
            $("#loscinco").show();
            $("#losseis").show();
            $("#lossiete").show();
            $("#losocho").hide();
            $("#losnueve").hide();
            $("#losdiez").hide();
        } else if (number === 8) {
            $("#loscuatro").show();
            $("#loscinco").show();
            $("#losseis").show();
            $("#lossiete").show();
            $("#losocho").show();
            $("#losnueve").hide();
            $("#losdiez").hide();

        } else if (number === 9) {
            $("#loscuatro").show();
            $("#loscinco").show();
            $("#losseis").show();
            $("#lossiete").show();
            $("#losocho").show();
            $("#losnueve").show();
            $("#losdiez").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hep9u/3/)

Comment: @AlejandroRamos I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: Really, thank you very much! You have solved a milestone in my project :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the change event to make it work on change of select

```
$('#integrantes').change(function(){

    var number= $('#integrantes :selected').val();

    if(number==3){
      $("#loscuatro").hide();
      $("#loscinco").hide();   
      $("#losseis").hide();   
      $("#lossiete").hide();   
      $("#losocho").hide();   
      $("#losnueve").hide();         
      $("#losdiez").hide();   

    }else if(number==4){
      $("#loscinco").hide();   
      $("#losseis").hide();   
      $("#lossiete").hide();   
      $("#losocho").hide();   
      $("#losnueve").hide();   
      $("#losdiez").hide();   

    }else if(number==5){
      $("#losseis").hide();   
      $("#lossiete").hide();   
      $("#losocho").hide();   
      $("#losnueve").hide();   
      $("#losdiez").hide();   

    }else if(number==6){   
      $("#lossiete").hide();  
      $("#losocho").hide();   
      $("#losnueve").hide();   
      $("#losdiez").hide();       

    } else if(number==7){
      $("#losocho").hide();   
      $("#losnueve").hide();   
      $("#losdiez").hide();
    }else if(number==8){
      $("#losnueve").hide();   
      $("#losdiez").hide();    

    }else if(number==9){
      $("#losdiez").hide();
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am sorry but I already tried your solution and it didn't work. :(

Comment: remove }); at the end of the line

Comment: please provide "JsFiddle".

Answer (score 0):

You have to chage **$(function(){...});** to **.change(function(){...})** by using select id

```
$(function(){
....
});
```

**to**

```
$('#integrantes').change(function(){
....
});
```

It calls, when you have to change your selected option

Comment: Hi Naveen. I already tried your solution but it didn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/6ZfVq/

Answer (score 0):

In your code you `hide()` your `div` but when the value of dropdown changed you not make visible these div's - so you need to `show()` div first-

My Code -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   DdlChange();
});

function DdlChange(){    
    var number= $('#integrantes :selected').val();
    $('.Showit').show(); //-- Show all div first
    if(number==3){
     $("#loscuatro").hide();
     $("#loscinco").hide();   
     $("#losseis").hide();   
     $("#lossiete").hide();   
     $("#losocho").hide();   
     $("#losnueve").hide();         
     $("#losdiez").hide();       
   }
   else if(number==4){
    $("#loscinco").hide();   
    $("#losseis").hide();   
    $("#lossiete").hide();   
    $("#losocho").hide();   
    $("#losnueve").hide();   
    $("#losdiez").hide();
  }
  else if(number==5){
    $("#losseis").hide();   
    $("#lossiete").hide();   
    $("#losocho").hide();   
    $("#losnueve").hide();   
    $("#losdiez").hide();
  }
  else if(number==6){   
    $("#lossiete").hide();  
    $("#losocho").hide();   
    $("#losnueve").hide();   
    $("#losdiez").hide(); 
  } 
  else if(number==7){
    $("#losocho").hide();   
    $("#losnueve").hide();   
    $("#losdiez").hide();
  }
  else if(number==8){
    $("#losnueve").hide();   
    $("#losdiez").hide(); 
  }
  else if(number==9){
    $("#losdiez").hide();
  }
}
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/UxcUx/2/)